# Discriminated unions without declaring all cases?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Consider a classic problem where the discriminated unions come useful:

```
type TShape = {
    type: string;
}

type TDrawing = {
    shapes: Array<TShape>;
}

const TypeRect = "rect";

type TRectangle = TShape & {
    type: typeof TypeRect;    //correct?
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

const TypeCircle = "cricle";

type TCircle = TShape & {
    type: typeof TypeCircle;  //correct?
    radius: number;
}
```

and many more.

Then an application of the above definitions:

```
const drawing: TDrawing = {
    shapes: [
        { type: TypeRect, width: 2, height: 3 },    //error
        { type: TypeCircle, radius: 5 },            //error
        { type: TypeRect, width: 10, height: 5 },   //error
    ]
}


function getCircles(drawing: TDrawing): Array<TCircle> {
    const a: Array<TCircle> = [];
    for (const shape of drawing.shapes) {
        if (shape.type === TypeCircle) {
            a.push(shape);    //error
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Now, consider the `TShape`-derived types are not necessairly known to the library where `TShape` is defined (think to a 2nd library containing other shapes).

First doubt: I'd need the `type` field at the `TShape` level to treat any kind of shape at its very basic structure. However, I also need the `type` specialization in order to discriminate the actual shape. Is it correct to redefine the field in the derived type?

Second problem: I couldn't find a way to let the compiler to infer the proper type, both in the array definition, and also in the loop. Is there a way to solve both?

Answer (score 0):

I think You are looking forsmth like this:

**UPDATED**

```js
type TShape = {
    type: string;
    id: string;
}

type TRectangle = TShape & {
    type: "rect";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

type TCircle = TShape & {
    type: "circle";
    radius: number;
}

type Circle = 'circle'
type Rect = 'rect'


type Shapes = TRectangle | TCircle

type TDrawing = {
    shapes: Array<Shapes>;
}


type TPolygon = TShape & {
    edgeCount: number;
}

const drawing: TDrawing = {
    shapes: [
        { type: 'rect', width: 2, height: 3, id: '1' },    //ok
        { type: 'circle', radius: 5, id: '2' },            //ok
        { type: 'rect', width: 10, height: 5, id: 2 },   // expected error, id should be string
        { type: 'circle' }, // expected error, no id, no raduis
        { type: 'circle', edgeCount: 8 }, // expected error, you don't allow extra properties
    ]
}

const requiredProps = ['id']
const hasProperties = <T, P extends string>(obj: T, props: P[]) => props.every(prop => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop))

const isCircle = (shape: Shapes): shape is TCircle => shape.type === 'circle' && hasProperties(shape, ['radius', ...requiredProps])


const isRect = (shape: Shapes): shape is TRectangle => shape.type === 'rect' && hasProperties(shape, ['width, height', ...requiredProps])

const getCircles = (drawing: TDrawing): Array<TCircle> => drawing.shapes.filter(isCircle)
const getRect = (drawing: TDrawing): Array<TRectangle> => drawing.shapes.filter(isRect)
```

Please let me know if it fit your requirements.

I'm not sure if you are aware about all possible union types ahead

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgZQBYENowLwwN7BvmcaALhgGcQAnASwDsBzAbjwOoBNSKaHmBfYUJFhwASlADGIFAwA2sLIlToAZDhb4iUUgCJKEkNuYEYAd3YgkpWgFcAtgCMolIwSRRq9JCCt3Hz4PyC6HAAwtSU4nKY8MhosKq4xpo64uGRUIbqMJQobNTWZD4OTnwCmjBhEVFYAOSpVVA1QbBiktE1epJNZUIwsdBk0aL60vRRAD7wlek9wQAiOWYM0YkEZEpQhTAAgpQ5YAA8-ZsAfKWzwgAKAPYyYPTXtEPHMAlZUGz0UCHX1rTeMBsxX8gXEjwoMDYizo9FIcAWKCW9BWWXWcS2AG0ssZsIQhKQOvoagAaUzmSwwABMpLcHi8pAAzKT2ASAIw1GC8UkEAD0POuAGtsQRcckYHU0nISdlcvktgBWZkccWUjlc4wa3n8oWa-Ci-HizogaVmNgWUisgAMNPcngBipgLKpnO5MD5MCgAA9oJIPh69tdKEryEhfjI2DBHOQqDDhXq8SRxfV0mrSe6vT6QH6nJRA6TaNdHWx84WcmxrNQyHGcAmtEnJY1SR8vj8-gCABwut08j3e-TZgNBmBgX6Qx41EAwFAyGTXEy9qgoGAQXPQSggaibLIAXQCAjBtAhegAjhW9GxLqvBlgMTV2DVdweIagyJfrmuN5togc4KTLguoFoNhBi4GETgACmuewACs4VJFd3y2S4MW3ABKTATmXK8ADooAANycMBwIQiAMJgAB5GD9GwhCQGuTRsJfciTFoN8PzAbDxGnGRIJg%20DV1Q1D93BSdK2maoYHAtFE2OMhUM4DZHUGUIGzI6SoGw8oMG0%20sGg5ZRVBfNinE-MgpI2UlbzLOVpWwuyTzPD42LINCBGAJ9RLIVpJywcy4lIWT5JDOIlPgbzRmqTD1M03ptNqI19MMlBX1XEzNzM9TLJqU0LBtOljVJOzsIc8InKvVz3JEmAvhAcSv18qFERhOEESRILdn2H86swjBMMapFsPUshsIAM2oGQs0ocCxIbISPOqqAQG86JwP65r4FamF2r2FBDmGSQIqgHq%20uhBhBo2Yaxompxpq8-QhOAIA)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. First off, suppose to define a `TPolygon` type having `edgeCount` as field. The drawing array will give you an error, unless you register the type in the `Shapes` union, but that's not always possible. Secondly, in the `getXXX` functions you're manually casting the `shape`, but that's less safe. BTW, I didn't use the "elegant way" because the discriminated unions inference does not work (unless you manually cast, of course).

Comment: @MarioVernari, could you please share in TS playground the error with `TPolygon` and `edgeCount` ? I don't have that error. Shapes is very generic type, see the lat union `Wrapper<{ type: string }>`

Comment: Feel free to play with, but I think you're also missing the safety of the types themselves. Apparently, you can set any kind of field in the drawing array, and that's not good. BTW, I also added a `id` field to the TShape type, so that all the derived types must define it. However, here is the link: https://shorturl.at/tvHMS

Comment: I don't have an error here: `edgeCount: 8`.
Answer is updated, I added typeguards. So you have 100% guarantee that Circle has radius, Rect has width and height etc... Also each shape has ID property.
THis code is much safer

Comment: Nope. There are at least two problems. First, the `id` field is required, and there's no error in the drawing array. Second, I can set an arbitrary field to that objects, and that shouldn't be allowed. Thank you for the effort, though.

Comment: It is not a problem to add ID field to generic restrictions. I made an update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228524/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-mario-vernari).